# Replacing a part from a given String

Tags: java, string, replace

I read content of a html file in a String. Inside html file are links containing this part "s1=some_user_elegance". I want to replace `some_user` to specified user;

```
String html = ....
String user = "John Davis"
String resultHTML = {all `"s1=some_user_elegance"` need to be replaced with `"s1=john_davis_elegance"}`
```

In addition, I don't know who is `"some_user"`. It can be anyone, but format is the same.

EDIT: found solution

```
public void identifyS1(String s) {
    String[] strings = s.split("\n");
    System.out.println(strings[28].substring(70, strings[28].length()).split(" ")[0].trim().replaceAll("\"", ""));
}
```

returns `"s1=whatever_user_elegance"`

I splited html file by new lines, found any line containing the URL and the rest was easy. Good thing is html will never change....

Comment: You can refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Did you do any research, like read the [documentation of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because very simple and certainly has too many answers on SO

Comment: Before voting to close question read it full. I know for replaceAll(); method, but it does not work, because "some_user" is dynamic, it can be "scot_peterson", it can be "ben_white" and therefore I don't know what to replace. If it was constant "some_user" replaceAll("some_user", "john_davis") would work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the specific regular expression to match and then call [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). The hard part is finding the regular expression which will match against your data perfectly. But, take a look at the following regex, it will replace anything between matching `s1=x_x_elegance`

```
String html = "{all `\"s1=some_user_elegance\"` need to be "
    + "replaced with `\"s1=john_davis_elegance\"`}";

System.out.println(html.replaceAll("s1=\\w+?_\\w+?_elegance",
"\"s1=john_davis_elegance\""));
```

**Result**

```
{all `""s1=john_davis_elegance""` need to 
be replaced with `""s1=john_davis_elegance""`}
```

Comment: replacing is easy, question is how can I find "s1=xxxx_yyyy_elegance"

Comment: yes, so you should probably tag your question with regular expression and provided more examples of your input data and expected output. I have provided a sample regex that has a reluctant quantifier and seems to work. Maybe this can be a starting point for you.

Comment: @ЂорђеЂашић take a look at the new regex I have provided it matches what you are looking for.